# Find the index of array where corruption begins

Tags: java, arrays

What will be the best solution to this question? **(Less than O(n))** 
Given an array of positive integers where successive elements increase by 1
(except for a single element that does NOT increase by one--the start of the
"corruption"), return the index of where the corruption starts.

Example 1:

> array:   [5,  6,  7,  8, 12, 13]   
> indices:  0   1   2   3   4   5

The corruption starts at index 4.

Example 2:

> array:   [5,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6]   
> indices:  0   1   2   3   4   5

The corruption starts at index 1.


P.S. My solution was of O(n), also I tried to branch it in two parts still it will reduce  half. 
Hint: I was told I can use binary search.

Edit:
My solution was simply to iterate the array and see if difference is greater or less than one.

Comment: Your solution was of O(n), cool! Can you please post that, too (even if it's pseudocode)?

Comment: My solution was simply to iterate the array and see if difference is greater or less than one.

Comment: You can use a sorting algorithm like merge sort and when you are doing the comparison if it's more than one that is the answer.

Comment: Since we are looking for single element, you can look at the start and end, verify that end element is `start + length + n` (where `n` is corruption), then split array in two parts and check in which part the above rule still holds, then continue to work with that part and ignore the other one.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov can you please provide the pseudo code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13};
        int res = checkArray(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
        System.out.println("res = " + res);
    }

    public static int checkArray(int[] nums, int start, int end) {
        if (end - start < 2) {
            return end;
        } else {
            int middle = (start + end) / 2;
            int a = nums[start];
            int b = nums[middle];
            if (b - a != middle - start) {
                return checkArray(nums, start, middle);
            } else {
                return checkArray(nums, middle, end);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It use the fact that difference between first and last element of subarray is equal to its length if array do not have corruption.

Comment: For this input I am getting 5: `5, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10`. Is this expected?

Comment: Yes. Because you have invalid input. Only one corruption is allowed.

Comment: @talex Thanks a lot for the solution :)

Comment: Why use recursion rather than a loop for this problem?

Comment: @Alex because, i think, it is pimplier to understand.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: @talex haha, yeah I figured that out. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // corruption starts at 13
    int[] arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17};

    int corruptionIndex = -1;

    int start = 0;
    int end = arr.length;

    while (end - start > 1) {
        int middle = (start + end) / 2;

        // we add the first element onto our value as an offset
        int expectedValue = middle + arr[0];

        if (arr[middle] != expectedValue) {
            // something has already gone wrong, let's check the first half
            end = middle;
        }
        else {
            // so far so good, let's check the second half
            start = middle;
        }

        corruptionIndex = end;
    }

    System.out.println("Corruption Index: " + corruptionIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr1 = [5, 9, 7, 8, 9, 13] ;
var arr2 = [5, 2] ;
var arr3 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13] ;
check(arr1);
check(arr2);
check(arr3);

function check(arr){
 for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
  if(arr[i]-arr[i-1] !=1 ){
   console.log('corroption begins at '+i);
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

we can check for current and prev element difference , right. if diff is not 1, we need to break. its in js

Answer (score -1):

O(n) is your only option. Binary search is O(log(n)) but that only works for searching for a specific number in a sorted list. You neither have a sorted list nor a specific number you are searching for

Comment: I only have one corrupted index hence it can be solution can be achieved by branching like we do in binary search.

Comment: In fact his list is sorted.

Answer (score -2):

```
class FindCorruptionIndex
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int i,j;
        int array[]={1,2,3,4,7,8,9};
        System.out.print("The array is [ ");
        for (int x :array )
        {
            System.out.print(x+",");
        }
        System.out.print("\b ] ");
        System.out.println();
        for(i=0;i<array.length-1;i++)
        {
            j=array[i+1]-array[i];
            if (j>=2)
            {
                System.out.println("The corruption Index position is "+(i+1));  
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: It is O(N). Question ask for better solution.